# How do I convert GBP to EUR?

Tags: c#, currency

I have a text box containing my balance and another text box I want to show the balance in euros. When I click the convert button I want it to be able to convert sterling to euro.

So how do I get my balance to display in streling and how do I get it to convert to euro?

Any example code would be great or even direct me to a site that will teach me this.

Comment: What hasn't worked for you so far and what's the currency exchange rate you're using?

Comment: Yea this is really just a matter of getting an exchange rate either by some webapi or just hard coding it.

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. You have to try to do something yourself and when you get stuck come here and ask _specific_ question.

Comment: Exchange rates are volatile. You'll need to contact an external service to get the current rate. [xe.com](http://xe.com) offers an API.

Answer (score 2):

The European Central Bank (ECB) provides the currency exchange rates on a daily basis in XML format

link for currency rates is [here](http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml)

use webrequest to save this xml and write your wrapper class to do the conversion

and if you want use xe.com use this [link](http://www.xe.com/wap/2co/convert.cgi?Amount=100&From=SGD&To=HUF), it has three parameters
    1.amount to convert, 2. from currency and 3. to currency

output of that link is

```
  <wml>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="must-revalidate" forua="true"/>
   <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" forua="true"/>
  </head>
  <card  title="XE Converter">
   <p mode="wrap" align="center">
    XE Converter
   </p>
   <p mode="nowrap" align="left">100 SGD =</p>
   <p mode="wrap" align="right">18,287.95 HUF</p>
   <p mode="wrap" align="center">
     Live @ 12:07 GMT
   </p> 
   <p mode="nowrap" align="left">
    <a href="step1.wml">Another?</a><br/>
    <a href="http://www.xe.com/wap/index.wml">XE Home</a>
   </p>
  </card>
  </wml>
```

again use webrequest class and get the output and parse that xml

sample is here

```
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = null;     //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;   //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class
        XmlDocument myXMLDocument = null;           //Declare XMLResponse document
        XmlTextReader myXMLReader = null;           //Declare XMLReader

        try
        {
            //Create Request
            myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.xe.com/wap/2co/convert.cgi?Amount=100&From=SGD&To=HUF");
            myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

            //Get Response
            myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            //Now load the XML Document
            myXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();

            //Load response stream into XMLReader
            myXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
            myXMLDocument.Load(myXMLReader);
        }
        catch (Exception myException)
        {
            throw  myException;
        }
        finally
        {
            myHttpWebRequest = null;
            myHttpWebResponse = null;
            myXMLReader = null;
        }
```